# Intuit - first connection

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

I have a question about Intuit API. I want to connect for the first time with this API. I'm using .NET SDK. I'm going througt this tutorial: http://goo.gl/PzIzoa . I don't know what i have to pass in arguments issuerId and subject (Step 1.b). I left them empty for the first try and I'm catching InvalidTokenException.
What arguments I have to pass to make it work?

Edit:
Thanks for your help, now I'm connecting via your web app.
Now I want to connect using my application. I wrote this code:

```
string certificateFile = "C:\\OpenSSL-Win32\\bin\\testapp1.crt";
string password = "xxx";
X509Certificate2 certificate = new X509Certificate2(certificateFile, password);
string consumerKey = "xxx";
string consumerSecret = "xxx";
string issuerId = "";
string subject = "";
SamlRequestValidator val = new SamlRequestValidator(certificate, consumerKey, consumerSecret, issuerId, subject);
```

After calling SamlRequestValidator constructor I'm catching InvalidTokenException. What am I doing wrong? What I have to do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at the following link.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/007_firstrequest

You can use apiexplorer tool to test these API calls without using devkit.
(It will ensure that your OAuth keys are working fine)

https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=CustomerAccountData

You can refer the following .Net sample app as well.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/devkits/285.net_sample_app_for_cad_services

Let me know if you get any issue related to this process.

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I have a problem with apiexplorer tool too. I don't have any file with *.p12 extension. How can i get it? During generating certificate it wasn't in output.

Comment: I've already shared the link to create .p12 file using ur .crt and .key file. Please follow the steps and generate the .p12 file and use the same in apiexplorer. 
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/Step_2:_Create_Your_X.509_Certificate

Comment: Thanks for your help. I've edited the question because i still have problems.

Comment: Did you try your tokens(to be specific - .p12 file with pwd) in CAD apiExplorer ?
https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=CustomerAccountData
(This is the easiest way to check if tokens are working fine)

.Net app setup link 
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/devkits/285.net_sample_app_for_cad_services/0010_creating_the_app

App Test Link - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/devkits/285.net_sample_app_for_cad_services/0015_testing_the_app

Best Wishes

Comment: I've just made it work. Thank you for your help and sorry for my dummy questions;)

Comment: np. glad to know that it helped you :)

Comment: Another small question. I'm testing your demo app. What I have to pass in form on InstitutionLogin?

Comment: You can refer this link - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata/customer_account_data_api/testing_calls_to_the_api
(You'll get all loginId and Pwds for the dummy Financial Insitituion ( CC_Bank, Id - 100000)

Comment: Hello again. I have a problem again. I tested whole api on my local machine and I wanted to deploy it on a server. I created new api with new certificate, configured config and it's not working. I'm getting internal error when I'm vreating service. Do you know what can be a problem?

Comment: I would suggest you to test those keys using apiexplorer
developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=CustomerAccountData.
I guess you got 500 error while trying DiscoverAndAddAccounts/any other Post request. Please check if the XML Post body is well defined.(You can share the XML in  your original post).

Comment: I'm not doing any requests because my service can't be constructed.
Also apiexplorer is working good.

Comment: did you try it in apiexplorer ? Please raise a support ticket attaching the screenshot of the error
https://developer.intuit.com/Support/Incident